# jQuery Insert ajax upload result into textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am designing a form with a textarea , which can be inserted ajax uploaded result (just a string of [image UUID] tag) . So that users can upload as many images as he/she wish (and adjust to proper position) .

This is my current working :

[image]

I use ajax to upload image file to server , and server will store (image) file and reply an [image UUID] string.

And I want the [image UUID] string auto inserted to the #textarea where the cursor stays.

The picture above works , but buggy and ugly.

- It works in Safari
- But not works in Firefox . It triggers AJAX twice , sending duplicated file , I don't know why.
- The "Upload" button is far beneath the #textarea , not intuitive for users.
- If I move the form2 directly beneath #textarea . It becomes **embedded form** . When ajax submits a file , it will trigger form2 and form1 , making form1 to submit.

form2's submit button :

```
<form id="ajaxFileUploadForm" method="post" th:action="@{/user/doAjaxUpload}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="ajaxFile" id="ajaxFile" class="btn btn-default"/>
  <button value="Upload" class="btn btn-default" onclick="uploadJqueryForm()" id="uploadImageButton">
    insert image
  </button>
</form>
```

and the JS code :

```
  <script th:inline="javascript">

    (function ($, undefined) {
      $.fn.getCursorPosition = function () {
        var el = $(this).get(0);
        var pos = 0;
        if ('selectionStart' in el) {
          pos = el.selectionStart;
        } else if ('selection' in document) {
          el.focus();
          var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
          var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
          Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
          pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        }
        return pos;
      }
    })(jQuery);

    //using jquery.form.js
    function uploadJqueryForm() {
      $('#uploadImageButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

      $("#ajaxFileUploadForm").ajaxForm({
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          var position = $("#textarea").getCursorPosition();
          var content = $('#textarea').val();
          var newContent = content.substr(0, position) + "\n" + data + "\n" + content.substr(position);
          $('#textarea').val(newContent);
          $('#uploadImageButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        },
        dataType: "text"
      }).submit();
    }

  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.51/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Is there any better solution , that can make the 'upload' button directly beneath #textarea , insert server reply to #textarea (cursor's position) , and works flawlessly cross browser ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that could be more intuitive for your users in the process to upload files or images is click whithin the textarea or drag and drop the image into the textarea. You can use many plugins like http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Greetings.

Comment: Is there an example that dropzonejs append result to an #textarea ?